# Can i use scrapy Post request without callback?

Tags: scrapy

I need to update location on site that uses redio button. This can be done with simple Post request. The problem is that output of this request is

```
window.location='http://store.intcomex.com/en-XCL/Products/Categories?r=True';
```

Since it is not a valid url Scrapy redirects it to PageNotFound and closes spider.

```
    2017-09-17 09:57:59 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https:
//store.intcomex.com/en-XCL/ServiceClient/PageNotFound> from <POST https://store.intcomex.com/en-XC
L//User/SetNewLocation>
```

Here is my code:

```
def after_login(self, response):
        # inspect_response(response, self)
        url = "https://store.intcomex.com/en-XCL//User/SetNewLocation"
        data={"id":"xclf1"
              }
        yield scrapy.FormRequest(url, formdata=data, callback = self.location)
        # inspect_response(response, self)

    def location(self, response):

        yield scrapy.Request(url = 'http://store.intcomex.com/en-XCL/Products/Categories?r=True', callback = self.categories)
```

The question is how can I redirect scrapy to valid url after executing Post request that changes location? Is there some argument that indicates target url or i can execute it without callback and yiel correct url on the next line?
Thanks.

Comment: Try `yield scrapy.FormRequest(url, formdata=data, callback = self.location, dont_redirect=True)`

Comment: I think you should create scrapy.Request manually from redirected page to goal page manually